# Начать исполнение заново

Tags: python

Мне нужно, чтобы после исполнение else(то есть когда введут не то, что нужно), опять начинался вывод со строки, в которой просят ввести метод взлома (`method = input('Chose...')`).

```
print('Hello! I am happy to see you here. It is program for hack password.')
method = input('Choose type of hack: A; B :')

#Выбран метод подгрузки паролей из словаря
if method == 'A':
    change = input('Choose type of hack : Gmail; Instagram; WLAN; : ')
    if change == 'Gmail':
        print('*You need to specify the exact path to the file with passwords.')
        passlist = input('Enter password_list: ')
        pass_found = open(passlist, 'r')
        user_name = input('Target email: ')
        server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.googlemail.com',587)
        server.ehlo()
        server.starttls()
else:
    print('Enter A or B!')
```

Comment: Используйте цикл `while` вместо `if`.

Comment: так мне нужно чтобы выводилась строка, что выше чем if

Answer (score 3):

Вместо

```
method = input('Choose type of hack: A; B :')

#Выбран метод подгрузки паролей из словаря
if method == 'A':
```

и

```
else:
    print('Enter A or B!')
```

используйте

```
method = None
while method not in ('A', 'B'):
    print('Enter A or B!')
    method = input('Choose type of hack: A; B :')
```